# Uploading multiple files using one form

Tags: php, pdo, upload, image-uploading

I am trying to create a form, with which a user can upload multiple image files.
I am still really at the start and I know that this code is very insecure. I just first would like to be able to upload the pictures and then I will add the rest afterwards.
I am working in a MVC structure and I am not using any CMS or famework.
**The view**

```
        <form action="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>image/uploadImages_action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple required />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload images" />
        </form>
```

**The Controller**

```
    /**
     * Upload images
     */
    public function uploadImages_action()
    {
        Auth::checkAuthentication();
        ImageModel::uploadImages();
        Redirect::to('login/showProfile');
    }
```

**The model**

```
public static function uploadImages()
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'])) {

            $files = $_FILES['images'];

            $allowed = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

            foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
                $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
                $file_size = $files['size'][$position];

                $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
                $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                    echo 'Image successfully uploaded.';
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code behaves very weird. I am able to upload some pictures and others not and I am only able to upload one picture at a time. If I choose more than one picture it uploads the last one seleceted.

I would be really happy for any kind of help I am stuck with this from hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will stop executing the loop once you run a return, like in your model's if statement. That's why you are only able to upload 1 picture. Removing that statement will probably fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! Now, I am still not able to upload certain pictures but at least I am one step further! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Because I lack the reputation to comment on your question though, I will ask here:  Could you clarify what kind of files you _weren't_ able to upload?

Comment: I have two files, which are identical except of their size. Both .jpg files. The one which can be uploaded is 84 KB big the one, which does not work is 5 MB big. I already lifted the limit in my php.ini to 40M and I have no restriction in my code. I also do not get any error message.

Comment: Have you double checked that by running `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` in your script? ;)

Comment: I had not. But it says 40M there as well.

Comment: I will figure it out somehow! You already helped me tremendosly! Thank you!!

Comment: Good luck! Just to be sure though, I forgot to ask what `ini_get('post_max_size')`  says.